# Objective C Singleton Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton

I have created a singleton class in Objective C. Like the one below:

```
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject{
   NSMutableArray *instanceArray;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *instanceArray;

+(SingletonClass*)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation SingletonClass
@synthesize instanceArray;

static SingletonClass *sharedInstance =nil;

+(SingletonClass*)sharedInstance
{
    if(sharedInstance==nil){
        sharedInstance=[[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}


-(id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        instanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [instanceArray addObject:@"One"];
        [instanceArray addObject:@"Two"];
    }
    return  self;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{   
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

@end
```

I know it can be accessed from anywhere with the following piece of code:

```
    SingletonClass *singletonObject=[SingletonClass sharedInstance];
```

And the instanceArray can be accessed anywhere by singletonObject.instanceArray.

Now my question is, is is possible to modify the array by adding new objects to it ? Will that be persisted ? Because i tried to add an object from one class

```
    [singletonObject.instanceArray addObject:@"Three"];
```

When i checked the array contents from another class, the array consisted of only two values  which are initialized by default. The value which i added from another class didnt show up.
What could be the problem ? Am I missing something here ? Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324732/using-a-singleton-to-create-an-array-accessible-by-multiple-views

Comment: If possible, format your code. It's difficult to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `allocWithZone:` implementation entirely.  It is prone to error and a distinctly odd thing to do.   The reality is that if you have code that is using your singleton class and *not going through `sharedInstance`* then that code is broken. Attempting to hide that brokenness is just going to cause pain later.

Just do this one:

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}
```

If you aren't seeing updates to the array in your other class, then there is some other bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `allocWithZone:` is never called because you are calling the `[super allocWithZone:]`, also i don't think you need this method.
i would change your class method with this:

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    if(sharedInstance==nil){
        sharedInstance = [[SingletonClass alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

and if you want to be more secure that you are not going to create another instance of your object use `dispatch_once`:

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: OP's `allocWithZone:` wasn't supposed to be called by his implementation because it'd be an infinite loop....

Answer (score -4):

I think that you forgot the ! before self in init method :

```
-(id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if(!self) {
        instanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [instanceArray addObject:@"One"];
        [instanceArray addObject:@"Two"];
    }
    return  self;
}
```

That's why each time you get a new instance of your singleton

Comment: Do not hesitate to tell why this is wrong ? Is his code correct with this (self) ?

Comment: it takes just a `!` to make it completely wrong.

Comment: @Shamanoid could you explain why you think it's right?

Comment: Go in your code and change and `init` method in one of your critical-to-your-app classes to use `if(!self) { ... initialize ... }` and see what happens!

Comment: Okkkkk I'understood and I apologize myself for this code @Popeye ...`if(!self)` before super init and `(self)` before init members. Am I right ?

Comment: no, you are not right. but do u really expect us to teach u objective-c in comments?