# How can I have multiple copies of an object that are identical update while instantiated as separate objects in different view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, core-data, singleton

I'm trying to have multiple copies of a single product objects in different view controllers (i.e. you have a product in a shopping list and when you search queries web-service and returns searched products). There is a symbol on search tableviewCell if that product is in the shopping list.

I thought of two ways to do this:

1. Have an array in a singleton class that caches the products in a NSMutableDictionary by their id numbers and every time a products is created it check to see if there is one in its place. If so it just uses the product already there. I can have a setting in the product that states if it is on the shopping list or not.
2. Use core data. I tried to implement it but not sure how I can exactly do this. I was thinking of using core data so that when i update a product object it is also updated in other parts of the app using NSFetchedResultsController.

What is "standard practice" for this situation?

Let me know what you think and how you would approach this. Thanks!

Comment: Why have multiple copies??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use singleton pattern for your data manager class, which will hold your data in an array of Models (For e.g.: Product)

If you use singleton data manager (for e.g.: ProductManager) then your data (for e.g.: Product entities) would be persistent for all your class files in application life cycle mode.

Here you can find more information:

[Objective C Singleton Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610285/objective-c-singleton-class)

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if the shopping list doesnt need to be written to disk, option 1 is fine. if it does need to be written to disk, you can use core data.. or use sqlite, or NSArchiver. there are a few ways of storing data.